# Application variable across load balanced servers (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, application-state

We have a website that runs on two load balanced servers. We used the ASP.Net Application variable to make application state "online/ offline", or for some important messages across the application, 
So when i try update a application variable its available on one server but not on other.
How i can manage a application variable across load balanced servers. 
What may I use? Of course keeping it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using sticky sessions?  How often does the data change?  Is application cache even necessary?

One option: You can have each webserver store (and manage, refresh, invalidate) its own application cache.  But then you run the chance of storing different copies.

Another option: distributed cache such as memcached or ncache or something else.

Another option: read/write the data out to a shared disk.

Answer (score 0):

Store that information in a database that all servers have access to and access information from.