# How to implement HttpApplication in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to store login information of a `user` `globaly`. If user is logged in already , then if `another user` want to login from another PC somewhere than application must warn him that another `user` is also logged in with this `name`.

I dont' want to use `DataBase`. I think `HttpApplication` is a solution. But I can't understand its flow.

What I know is ,  I have to assign values to it in `Global.asax.cs` file :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
             Application["Username"] = "Test";
        }
   }
```

Now i want to access it in a `controller` , in `Login Function` where I would check if `Application` has some data or not.

If it is `null` than there is no `user` logged in.  But I don't understand how to access `HTTPApplication` object and how to assign the `username` to it in the `Application_Start()`.

Comment: Keep in mind that once the `application pool` is recycled, you lose all your `Application` data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a controller you can access the application object. Ie.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string value = HttpContext.Application["a"] as string;
            if (value == null){
                value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                HttpContext.Application["a"] = value;
            }

            return Content(value);                
        }
```

Comment: Actually I want to store whole object of the user , it contains some additional information.

Comment: I did this: 

`string obj = HttpContext.Application["a"];
if(obj == null )
{
 HttpContext.Application["a"] = "b";
}`

And on every new request , it is entering in `if` condition i.e. obj is null

Comment: ??? This makes no sense... have you got a load balancer or more then one web server? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449709/application-variable-across-load-balanced-servers-asp-net

Comment: There are no load balancers , and web server is also one

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string value = HttpContext.Current.Application["a"] as string;
```